# Overwrite review template and review list block magento

Tags: magento-1, template

This is my layout:

```
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="namespace_module/review_product_view_list" name="review_productaa" template="namespace_module/product/view/list.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

in the etc.xml I managed to rewrite my block:

```
<rewrite>
     <product_view_list>Namespace_Module_Block_Review_Product_View_List</product_view_list>
</rewrite>
```

My block:

```
  class Namespace_Module_Block_Review_Product_View_List extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List
  {
     public function addNewProductReviewLink(){

        return "test";
    }
  }
```

My problem is with my template. Why I got invalid method if i call the addNewProductReviewLink function in my template,like `echo $this->addNewProductReviewLink();` ?

Comment: what is your problem with your template can you explain it?

Comment: Whats the issue. You can just add html on your template phtml file.

Comment: Right now the block rewrite part is working , but I still get the old phml file and i want to change that into a custom one.